# Wikidata Query misses results

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to query all the countries from Wikidata ([query link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256.%20%7D)):

```
SELECT ?item WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q6256. }
```

Unfortunately, the results are missing for example Switzerland (`Q39`):

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q39

Looking at the Switzerland data, it has the triple: `instance of` (P31) `country` (Q6256).
Could you help me understand why `Q39` is not present in the results then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WikiData, often you have what are called statements. These allow for qualifications to those statements.
For instance, in the case of Switzerland being a country, the qualification is that the rank of this statement should be 'normal' instead of preferred.
The preferred way to refer to Switzerland is sovereign state (wd:Q3624078), and it looks like WikiData will only have a wdt:P31 relationship between an entity and its 'preferred rank' classification only, as this [query](https://w.wiki/34Fn) shows.

I think this could be because 'country' is a more generic concept, e.g. Wales is a country but not a sovereign state.

Fear not however, as this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item
WHERE { 
  ?item p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q6256. 
}
```

returns wd:Q39 as well. What this query is doing is to navigate from Switzerland to Country *via* the statement.
That is, we have in our data:

```
wd:Q39 p:P31 wds:Q39-fbe1ac75-4a8a-93c4-6009-81055d79f9cb .
wds:Q39-fbe1ac75-4a8a-93c4-6009-81055d79f9cb ps:P31 wd:Q6256 .
```

but not:

```
wd:Q39 wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 .
```

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE { 
  ?item p:P31 ?y .
  ?y ps:P31 wd:Q6256 ;
     ?p ?o .
  VALUES ?item {wd:Q39}
}
```

to see for yourself.